How to Run 40+ Jobs Concurrently in AWS Batch Without Exceeding Time Limits
I'm currently using AWS Batch to run multiple jobs concurrently, but I'm facing issues with job timeouts. My goal is to run more than 40 jobs at a time, but some jobs are failing due to exceeded time limits.
{
  "jobDefinitionName": "xyz",
  "jobDefinitionArn": "xxx",
  "revision": 11,
  "status": "ACTIVE",
  "type": "container",
  "parameters": {},
  "containerProperties": {
    "image": "yyy",
    "command": [],
    "jobRoleArn": "yyy",
    "executionRoleArn": "yyy",
    "volumes": [],
    "environment": [],
    "mountPoints": [],
    "ulimits": [],
    "user": "root",
    "resourceRequirements": [
      {
        "value": "4.0",
        "type": "VCPU"
      },
      {
        "value": "8192",
        "type": "MEMORY"
      }
    ],
    "logConfiguration": {
      "logDriver": "awslogs",
      "options": {},
      "secretOptions": []
    },
    "secrets": [],
    "networkConfiguration": {
      "assignPublicIp": "DISABLED",
      "interfaceConfigurations": []
    },
    "fargatePlatformConfiguration": {
      "platformVersion": "LATEST"
    },
    "runtimePlatform": {
      "operatingSystemFamily": "LINUX",
      "cpuArchitecture": "X86_64"
    }
  },
  "timeout": {
    "attemptDurationSeconds": 7200
  },
  "tags": {},
  "platformCapabilities": [
    "FARGATE"
  ],
  "containerOrchestrationType": "ECS"
}

Problems:
Jobs Not Running Concurrently: Even though I submit multiple jobs, they do not start running immediately. Only a few jobs run concurrently, and others remain in a "runnable" state.
Job Timeouts: Some jobs fail due to exceeding the timeout duration.
What I've Tried:
Ensured the compute environment is configured to handle the necessary number of vCPUs and memory.
Verified that the job queue is active and has enough capacity.
Checked AWS service limits for vCPUs and other resources in the region.
Questions:

How can I configure AWS Batch to run 40+ jobs concurrently without hitting timeouts?
What settings should I adjust in the compute environment or job definition to achieve this?
Are there any best practices for managing large numbers of concurrent jobs in AWS Batch?

Any guidance or examples would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

40 concurrent Fargate resources are pretty small number. Some questions: (1) What is the expected runtime of jobs? Batch is tuned for jobs that are 4+ minutes. (2) Are positive you have sufficient Fargate quota? This is separate from EC2 capacity quotas. (3) Is your compute environment configured to run across all AZs in the Region?
